# Phonegap - Cannot create new project

Tags: cordova, windows-10, phonegap

I've just done a fresh install of both Phonegap Desktop and CLI. Both of them return

```
Error: Unhandled "error" event. (  Error from Cordova Fetch: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT)
```

(in CLI and something similar in desktop). I already tried some of the fixes recommended in other threads concerning the issue, but none of them were helping.

I'm using Windows 10.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what's your node, phonegap and cordova version?
you can check using node -v command.

Comment: This usually occurs due to incompatible node and npm versions. Try installing node version 6.11.0 and npm version 3.10.0 . I have personally found these to be stable for cordova installations

Comment: Phonegap Cordova Version is 7.1.0 and node is at 8.9.2. Is there really no up-to-date setup which should be working?